# Adding additional entry to observable returned data to be used at the api call level

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a number of food item list services like:

```
getFruits(): Observable<Fruit[]> {
    return this.apiService.get<Fruit[]>(this.fruitUrl);
}
```

I have many forms where they call this for the entire list of items then user saves the form. I have a feature where user can delete items from the list (e.g. remove Apple from fruits list) but when user loads a saved form, i want the original fruit item to be in the list if it was removed (e.g. if Apple was removed after I saved a form with Apple as part of dropdown. When I load the list the Apple needs to be there). What I want is to add the missing selected item to the list IF it wasn't in there.

I did look around and it seems a lot of solutions revolves around after getting the data then add new entry to it. With so many forms I have I don't think thats ideal. Is there a way to add the entry to the "getFruits()" by passing in the Fruit name and if it doesnt exist then I add the entry then return the result?

I tried something like

```
    let fruits = this.apiService.get<Fruit[]>(this.fruitUrl);
 let newFruit = new Fruit();
 newFruit.name = "Apple";
 newFruit.id = 999;
 let fruits1;
 fruits.pipe(map(fruits1=> [...fruits1, newFruit]));

return fruits;
```

but the list is still what was returned from the call. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried the map operator?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use **tap** to modify an array.  Instead use **map** to create a new one.

```
fruits.pipe(map(fruits1=> [...fruits1, newFruit]));
```

In general you'll be happier not modifying things and just creating new instances.  The lack of side effects is a good thing.

Comment: so i updated the code snippet. didn't get errors but the list still doesnt have the new value...

Comment: You need to `return fruits.pipe(...);` rather than `return fruits;`

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to add the entry to the "getFruits()" by passing in the Fruit name and if it doesnt exist then I add the entry then return the result*

Use `map` with a ternary condition:

```
getFruits(newFruit: Fruit): Observable<Fruit[]> {
    return this.apiService.get<Fruit[]>(this.fruitUrl).pipe(
      map(fruits => fruits.find(f => f.name === newFruit.name)
        ? fruits 
        : [...fruits, newFruit]
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: So the above did work for mockdata BUT here is a new wrinkle i discovered. There could be multiple Fruit objects passed in AND they are incomplete so I need to make a service call at some point to get the full Fruit object like apiService.getById(id) (or id[]?)

How would that play out? 

So I would like to do it so that I iterate through the Fruits passed in, if I dont find an entry by name i add the newFruit. But how do i iterate through a loop inside that map and for : [...fruits, newFruit], can the newFruit be an apiService call to get an individual Fruit? Thanks

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to just create new backend API to accept an array of IDs and query that way.

Comment: Are you sure you would know the IDs of the incomplete fruits? That is unlikely if they are newly entered.

Comment: yes, the form i load will have their ID only. so even if i find the missing IDs, i will need to retrieve it again for the full object... it is a pain right now .

Comment: If you need the complete Fruits, then that is what your original 'getAll' API should provide you. If it doesn't you are in the current situation where you having to accommodate by requesting and merging the data on the FE.

Comment: the current "getall" returns non-deleted items, which is used when user is starting fresh. but once the saves the form then the "getall" should be items that are not deleted AND the item the user selected . I am trying to do
1. create API that sends the ID then the backend query will filter them in.
2. get a true "getAll" then i filter out the deleted minus the item user selected.  
I am getting path issues from our service controller:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166306/how-to-configure-rest-controller-to-accept-a-path-variable-that-is-dynamic/71166600#71166600
so maybe 1is best

Comment: To be honest it all sounds rather (probably overly) convoluted. In any case would you mind accepting my answer or at least upvoting it, If you are happy with it in relation to the original question?