# How to configure rest controller to accept a path variable that is dynamic?

Tags: java, rest

I have an api call that performs a get like:
http://localhost/foo/barCodes?0=XXX&1=ZZZ?2=YYY
It can be more or less depending on the user's actions..
For the backend Restcontroller, initially i tried

```
 @GetMapping("/foo/barCodes")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Food>> getSomeFood(
      @RequestParam String[] codes) {
```

but i get error Bad Request', message: "Required request parameter 'codes' for method parameter type String[] is not present". I also looked at pathvariable but those seems to be static.

I did think about parsing out maybe have the values separated by ":" like XXX:ZZZ:YYY or XXX:YYY then that would be one value and I can split it.  Is there a different way about it?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Mapping a Multi-Value Parameter**

List of values can be passed via URL like this:

```
http://localhost:12345/foo/barCodes?codes=firstValue,secondValue,thirdValue
```

OR

```
http://localhost:12345/foo/barCodes?codes=firstValue&codes=secondValue&codes=thirdValue
```

In spring rest controller, they can be received like this:

```
@GetMapping("/foo/barCodes")
public void getSomeFood(@RequestParam String[] codes) {
   // Handle values here
}
```

OR

```
@GetMapping("/foo/barCodes")
public void getSomeFood(@RequestParam List<String> codes) {
   // Handle values here
}
```

**2. Mapping All Parameters**

We can also have multiple parameters without defining their names or count by just using a `Map`. But in this case you need to change GET to POST method.

```
@PostMapping("/foo/barCodes")
public String getSomeFood(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
       // Handle values here    
}
```

Request json example:

```
{
    "Par1":"Val1",
    "Par2":"Val2"
}
```

OR

```
curl -X POST -F 'Par1' -F 'Val1' http://localhost:12345/foo/barCodes
```

Comment: I think the current way we send the request the parameters are dynamically named "barCodes?0=XXX&1=ZZZ?2=YYY" and I would rather not mess with that as much as possible...
But for the pattern:?codes=firstValue,secondValue,thirdValue. I could use what i was thinking before of concatenating the parameters into ?0=xxx,yyy,zzz  by appending ","+ nextvalue as part of an entire parameter and maybe that tricks the controller into thinking it is String[] codes ?

Comment: I think, in your case Solution 1 will work. Send data like: ?codes=XXX,YYY,ZZZ and then access to each parameter via array index at server side.